# Yocto generated nativesdk-cmake SDK is incomplete

Tags: linux, cmake, sdk, yocto

For the past couple of days I have been trying to generate a viable CMake SDK with Yocto Project. I'm trying to generate SDK based on an image file which is given below:

```
#To build SDK, use bitbake meta-toolchain

DESCRIPTION = "Embeddev-LXDE image."

LICENSE="CLOSED"

IMAGE_INSTALL = "packagegroup-core-boot \
    packagegroup-core-x11 \
    packagegroup-lxde-base \
    kernel-modules \
"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nano git cmake qtbase qtchooser dbus packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh xterm"

#Framebuffer driver for tft
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " xf86-video-fbdev"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " apt dpkg sudo tzdata glibc-utils localedef networkmanager pointercal xinit xkeyboard-config base-passwd liberation-fonts pkgconfig"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " wiringpi"

#Maybe consider connman instead of networkmanager
#vc-graphics is problematic with userland..

inherit populate_sdk

## SDK stuff, to build sdk use bitbake rpi-embeddev-lxde-image -c populate_sdk
# Add all static packages:  SDKIMAGE_FEATURES += "staticdev-pkgs"
SDKIMAGE_FEATURES += "staticdev-pkgs"
SDKIMAGE_FEATURES += "dev-pkgs"
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " wiringpi-dev"
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-cmake"
##
inherit distro_features_check
REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "x11"

IMAGE_LINGUAS ?= " "

LICENSE = "MIT"

export IMAGE_BASENAME = "rpi-embeddev-lxde-image"

inherit core-image

ENABLE_SPI_BUS = "1"
ENABLE_I2C = "1"

# qtwebengine qtwebkit ...

do_image_prepend() {

}
```

I create my SDK with `bitbake rpi-embeddev-lxde-image -c populate_sdk`.

I would like to describe the exact problem. The problem is that `nativesdk-cmake` is not correctly installed in the SDK. Cmake 3.10.2 recipe gives:

```
do_install_append_class-nativesdk() {
    mkdir -p ${D}${datadir}/cmake
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/OEToolchainConfig.cmake ${D}${datadir}/cmake/

    mkdir -p ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/environment.d-cmake.sh ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/cmake.sh
}

FILES_${PN}_append_class-nativesdk = " ${SDKPATHNATIVE}"

FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/cmake-${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}"
FILES_${PN}-doc += "${docdir}/cmake-${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "nativesdk"
```

Tracing the root of the problem, I have seen that the `cmake/` directory that should be created is created in:

```
/home/<user>/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-cmake/3.10.2-r0/image/opt/poky/2.4+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/
```

However, this cmake directory is not valid in `/opt/poky/2.4+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/`, -where it is actually needed- when I install the SDK to `/opt`, unfortunately.

Do I need to know anything else or do anything else regarding how to properly generate SDK?

I am really stuck here any help is much appreciated indeed.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I moved `TOOLCHAIN_TASK` statements to layer.conf and used `bitbake meta-toolchain` which also didn't work.

**EDIT2**: I used cmake version 3.6 with `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_cmake = "3.6.1"`, which also did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the imminent Yocto Project 2.5, Sumo, release. Here, `sysroots/x86_64-chargestorm-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake` seems to be omitted.

The temporary solution for this is to add

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "nativesdk-cmake-dev"
```

And yes, using a release is always helpful, especially if your new to some project. Just remember to always use the same release branches for all your included layers. And personally, I'd not start a new project based on Morty, which was released 1.5 years ago when writing this, as it's likely to go out of official Yocto Project support rather soon.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, it seems that it is still a bug (Or would this be mis-feature at this point...?) in Sumo.  Just got bit by this...workaround looks to be the same as described.

(Note: This ***is*** a release at this point in time...  X-D)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using a release (I used "morty", and not the "master branch") for every layer and poky itself. This is apparently very important.

Comment: Morty is a release prior to the misfeature being added.  

1) Unless you need it, you're better off using Sumo or Thud for the release...
2) ...and if so, you need to use the workaround.

Comment: The problem is solved, I am using thud at the moment. Thanks for reminder